# Url build. What does really this URL mean?

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, hyperlink, path

I have a small question about links.
There is a link:

> site.com/some_site?get=page2

Why if I add ".php" to "some_site" word it will not work?
If I add ".php" to "page2" word, it works.

I am just thinking what does really "some_site" is. Is it a folder or a file modified by .htaccess file, so it won't work, when I add something after dot like "php", "html" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general (because it is possible to screw around with these things with server side code):

The local path (between the end of the hostname and the first `?` or `#` or the end of the URL) is used to identify some predefined entry point on the server. That might be represented by a file, by a function in a server side program or by something else.

The query string (between the first `?` and the first `#` or the end of the URL) represents data which gets handled by that entry point.

So if you change the entry point you are looking for, then the server is going to complain that it can't find it (because you used a name that doesn't exist).

If you change the data in the query string, then you are just changing the data you expecting that entry point to handle.